# Object Coordinates

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to draw a rectangle and place the top left corner at coordinates x=3, y=7 using a millimeter scale (or inch scale).  How do I accomplish this?  Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the rectangle to somewhere. Select it.

In the info bar click "top left" in the reference point selector

Type the wanted coordinates to X and Y placement coordinate boxes. Here the coordinates are 7 mm and 8 mm:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!  I have a different version of AI and figured out just the way you explained!